# Linked list to manage a class

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm working on a linked list to save the information of students. I can insert anywhere on the list, delete and sort it. Now i'm reviewing the code to try to simplify it somehow. I don't know if the .c's and the .h's of the project are correctly arranged.

The program complies and runs as it should.

Do you think the methods and the modules are OK ?
Is this 'correct' programming?

main.c

```
    #include "linked_list.h"
#include "main.h"

// Functions
void display_student (node_t node) 
{
    printf ("number: %d; name: %s; team: %d\n",node->student.number, node->student.name,node->student.team);
}
void display_list (list_t list, void (*displaystudent) (node_t node)) 
{
     int counter=0;
     node_t node = NULL;

     node = list->head;
     while (node != NULL) 
     {
         counter+=1;
         printf("%d-",counter);
         (*displaystudent) (node);
         node = node->next;
     }
}
void insert_top(list_t list, node_t node) 
{
    node->next = list->head;    
    list->head = node; 
}
int insert_middle(list_t list,node_t node, int position)
{
    struct node *tmpPtr = list->head;
    int count=2;
    if(position==1 || list->head==NULL)
    {
      insert_top(list,node);
    }
    else
    {
      while(count!=position && tmpPtr->next!=NULL)  
      {
          tmpPtr=tmpPtr->next;
          count+=1;
      }
      node->next=tmpPtr->next;
      tmpPtr->next=node;
    }
}
int insert_tail(list_t list, node_t node)
{
    struct node *tmpPtr = list->head;
    if(list->head==NULL)
        return FALSE;
    while(tmpPtr->next!=NULL)
        tmpPtr=tmpPtr->next;
    node->next=tmpPtr->next;
    tmpPtr->next=node;
}
void sort(list_t list,node_t node, int x) 
{
    node_t temp = (node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *tmpPtr = list->head;
    struct node *tmpNxt = list->head->next;
    while(tmpNxt != NULL)
    {
        while(tmpNxt != tmpPtr)
        {
            if(x==numbers)
            {
                if(tmpNxt->student.number<tmpPtr->student.number)
                {
                    temp->student=tmpPtr->student;
                    tmpPtr->student=tmpNxt->student;
                    tmpNxt->student=temp->student;
                }
                tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
            }
            if(x==names)
            {
                if(_stricmp(tmpNxt->student.name,tmpPtr->student.name)<0)
                {
                    temp->student=tmpPtr->student;
                    tmpPtr->student=tmpNxt->student;
                    tmpNxt->student=temp->student;
                }
                tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
            }
            if(x==teams)
            {
                if(tmpNxt->student.team<tmpPtr->student.team)
                {
                    temp->student=tmpPtr->student;
                    tmpPtr->student=tmpNxt->student;
                    tmpNxt->student=temp->student;
                }
                tmpPtr = tmpPtr->next;
            }
        }
        tmpPtr = list->head;
        tmpNxt = tmpNxt->next;
    }
    free(temp);
}
int open_file(const char *filename,list_t list, node_t node)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[MAX];
    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    while(fgets(buffer,MAX,fp))
    {
        node = (node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        node=process_line(node,buffer);
        if(node==FALSE)
            return FALSE;
        insert_top(list,node);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return TRUE;
}
int close_file(const char *filename, list_t list, node_t node)
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen(filename,"w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    do {
        node = remove_top (list);
        fprintf(fp,"%d;%d;%s;\n",node->student.number, node->student.team,node->student.name);
        free(node);
        } while (freeList(list) != NULL);
    fclose(fp);
    return TRUE;
}
int Menu()
{
    int input = 1;
    int num = 0;
    int n=0;
    list_t list = NULL;
    node_t node = NULL;
    //le code
    list=newList();
    if(open_file(FILENAME,list,node)==FALSE)
    {
        RETURN(1);
    }
    while (input != 0) 
    {
        printf("\n-- Menu --\n0) Exit\n1) Insert top\n2) Insert end\n3) Insert N\n4) Delete\n5) Show list\n6) list number\n7) list names\n8) list teams\n");
        scanf("%d", &input);
        switch (input) 
        {
        case 0:
            input = 0;
            if(close_file(FILENAME,list,node)==FALSE)
            {
                RETURN(1);
            }
            printf("end!\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            //node = (node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            //node = create_node((node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node)));
            insert_top(list,create_node((node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node))));
            break;
        case 2:
            //node = (node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            //node = create_node(node);
            insert_tail(list,create_node((node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node))));
            break;
        case 3:
            //node = (node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            printf("insert in: ");
            scanf("%d",&n);
            //node = create_node(node);
            insert_middle(list,create_node((node_t) malloc(sizeof(struct node))),n);
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("Node to delete: ");
            scanf("%d", &num);
            if(node=remove_node(list,node,num))
            {
                printf("%s deleted\n",node->student.name);
                free(node);
            }
            else
            printf(" not found\n"); 
            break;
        case 5:
            display_list(list, display_student);
            break;
        case 6:
            sort(list,node,numberS);
            display_list(list, display_student);
            break;
        case 7:
            sort(list,node,nameS);
            display_list(list, display_student);
            break;
        case 8:
            sort(list,node,teamS);
            display_list(list, display_student);
            break;
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    Menu();
    RETURN(0);
}
```

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_
#define MAIN_H_

#define FILENAME "data.csv"

void display_student (node_t) ;
void display_list (list_t, void (*) (node_t)) ;
void insert_top(list_t, node_t) ;
int insert_middle(list_t,node_t, int);
int insert_tail(list_t, node_t);
void sort(list_t,node_t, int) ;
int open_file(const char *,list_t, node_t);
int close_file(const char *, list_t, node_t);
int Menu();

#endif
```

linked_list.c

```
#include "linked_list.h"

// Node & List operations
list_t newList()
{
    list_t list=NULL;
    list = (list_t)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    list->head=NULL;
    return (list);
}
list_t freeList (list_t list) 
{  
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        free (list);
        list = NULL;
    }
    return (list);
}
node_t remove_top (list_t list) 
{
    node_t node = NULL;
    if (list->head != NULL) 
    {
        node = list->head;
        list->head = node->next;
    }
    return (node);
 }
node_t remove_node(list_t list, node_t node, int x) 
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp1;
    struct node *temp=list->head;
    if(x==1)
    {
        list->head=temp->next;
        return temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<x-2;i=i+1)  
    {
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp1=temp->next;
    temp->next=temp1->next;
    return temp1;
}
node_t process_line(node_t node,char *buffer)
{
    char *p;
    p=strchr(buffer,';');
    if(!p)
    {   printf("Error opening file\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    *p='\0';
    node->student.number=atoi(buffer);
    buffer=p+1;
    p=strchr(buffer,';');
    if(!p)
    {   printf("Error opening file\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    *p='\0';
    node->student.team=atoi(buffer);
    buffer=p+1;
    p=strchr(buffer,';');
    if(!p)
    {   printf("Error opening file\n");
        return FALSE;
    }
    *p='\0';
    strcpy(node->student.name,buffer);
    return node;
}
node_t create_node(node_t node)
{
        srand(time(NULL));
        printf("Insert number: ");
        scanf("%d",&node->student.number);
        getchar();
        //node->student.number = rand() % 1000 + 1;
        printf("Insert name: ");
        gets(node->student.name);
        printf("Insert team: ");
        scanf("%d",&node->student.team);
        //node->student.team = rand() % 4 + 1;
        node->next = NULL;
        return (node);
}
```

linked_list.h

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
#define numbers 2
#define names 3
#define teams 4
#define MAX 50
#define RETURN(x) \
        system("PAUSE"); \
        return x;

// Struct and List definition
typedef struct student
{
    int number;
    char name[MAX];
    int team;
}student_t;

struct node
{
    student_t student; 
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node *node_t;

struct list {
     node_t head;
};
typedef struct list *list_t;

list_t newList();
list_t freeList(list_t);
node_t remove_top(list_t);
node_t remove_node(list_t,node_t,int);
node_t process_line(node_t,char *);
node_t create_node(node_t);
```

Comment: I'm not reviewing code with non english identifiers. Sorry.

Comment: @EmilyL. you're right, I should have changed it . Mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is fairly easy to read and straightforward, which should make it easier to maintain in the future. Nice work!

## Naming

Many of your names are very good. Names like `newList()`, `display_student()`, etc. are easy to understand. A few are not, though. `free_list()` for example, does not free the list, unless it is already empty. A casual reader of the code would probably assume that if you want to free the entire list, then you should call a function named `free_list()`.

Your type naming seems a little confusing to me, too. When I see a type definition followed by `typedef <some type> some_type_t`, I expect variables of that type to be of `<some type>` and not a pointer to `<some type>`. Usually a defined pointer type is declared something like:

```
typedef struct node *node_ptr;
```

This lets the reader know that this is a pointer and not the actual structure.

Your naming is also slightly inconsistent in that you are using underscores between words in function names in some cases, and camel-casing in other cases. Either is fine, but it's probably best to stick to one or the other.

Also, parameter and variable names like `x` and `temp` and `temp1` are not at all descriptive.

## Handling Failure

There are a few places where you aren't properly handling failure cases. In `newList()`, for example, you don't handle the case where allocation of the list fails:

```
list_t newList()
{
    list_t list=NULL;
    list = (list_t)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    // The above allocation could fail, so we have to handle it before
    // setting list->head
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    list->head=NULL;
    return (list);
}
```

Any function that takes a `list_t` or a `node_t` will crash if passed NULL for those parameters.

## Self-documenting Code

As mentioned, a lot of your naming is pretty good and that goes a long way towards telling a reader its intent. I think you could improve it in a few places by using the language a little more.

For example, you have these macros declared:

```
#define numbers 2
#define names 3
#define teams 4
```

That's a good start! You aren't using magic numbers, which is good, but why not turn it into a type? Something like this:

```
typedef enum categories {
    numbers = 2,
    names,
    teams
} categories;
```

Also, why start at 2 instead of 0?

I would also shy away from using macros for constants and instead use named constants like this:

```
const size_t MAX_NAME_LEN = 50;
```

Comment: thank you for commenting! Will try to keep that in mind in the future.